# findViewById in RecyclerView ViewHolder throws NullPointerExcpetion

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display data with a `RecyclerView`. I'm not too sure why it keep crashing with a `NullPointerException`. My theory is that it is trying to find the `TextView` before the view itself has been created.

However, with the way my constructor is, it shouldn't be doing that.

Been at this for a couple hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="@color/icons" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:text="price"
            android:textColor="@color/icons"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_name"
            android:textColor="@color/icons"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class ExpenseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpenseAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Item> mExpenseList;

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView frag_name;
        public TextView frag_price;
        public TextView frag_date;


        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            frag_name.findViewById(R.id.recycler_name);
            frag_price.findViewById(R.id.recycler_price);
            frag_date.findViewById(R.id.recycler_date);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expense, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // constructor to receive list of expenses for recycler view to process
    public ExpenseAdapter(ArrayList<Item> expenseList) {
         mExpenseList = expenseList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
        Item currItem = mExpenseList.get(i);

        itemViewHolder.frag_name.setText(currItem.getName());
        itemViewHolder.frag_price.setText(Integer.toString(currItem.getPrice()));
        itemViewHolder.frag_date.setText(currItem.getDatePurhase());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExpenseList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: `frag_name.findViewById(R.id.recycler_name);` – That's not how to do that there. It would be `frag_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_name);`, and similarly for the others.

Comment: `TextView.findViewById()` is a) non-sense and b) `null`... try `itemViewHolder.findViewById()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize views in your `ItemViewHolder` before using them. Right now `frag_name.findViewById(R.id.recycler_name)` will throw `NullPointerException` cause your trying to use wrong view to `findViewById()`.

Use this code:

```
public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        frag_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_name);
        frag_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_price);
        frag_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_date);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i feel dumb for asking this questions